# Filter directories in piped input

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash command that lists a number of files and directories. I want to remove everything that is not an existing directory. Is there anyway I can do this without creating a script of my own? I.e. I want to use pre-existing programs available in linux.

E.g. Given that I have this folder:

```
dir1/
dir2/
file.txt
```

I want to be able to run something like:

```
echo dir1 dir2 file.txt somethingThatDoesNotExist | xargs [ theCommandIAmLookingFor]
```

and get

```
dir1
dir2
```

Comment: Are those directories nested or just sub-directories of current path?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A stack trace alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Remove from the list? Or remove from filesystem? How complicated a command counts as a script? What is the format of the list?

Comment: Question clarified

Comment: Why are you using `echo` and `xargs`?  It seem like you want `find . -type d`

Comment: Or perhaps `... | while read p; test -d "$p" && echo "$p"; done` which has some issues, but most of those are probably not relevant if you are assuming your input indeed contains newline separated values.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I am not using echo. I get the input from another program. This is just to illustrate how it would work. If there is a bash solution it should be generic enough to handle both echo and my real case. xargs might not be needed.

Comment: echo dir1 dir2 file.txt somethingThatDoesNotExist | sh -c 'read l; find $l -maxdepth 0 -type d'

Comment: Probably there's a problem if files or directories have spaces and other "non-regular" characters in their names, but then you need to specify rules how these names are printed by the program.

Comment: or `...| xargs -n 1 sh -c 'test -d "$0" && echo $0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better if the command generating the putative paths used a better delimeter, but you might be looking for something like:

```
... | xargs -n 1 sh -c 'test -d "$0" && echo $0'
```

Comment: Honestly I'm quite surprised there isn't a dedicated program for this. Seems to me like it's a rather common (at least not rare) problem. Maybe it's related to the evolution of programming paradigms - this kind of "filtering" design pattern is much more common in functional (as opposed to imperative) programming, which has only seen practical use in relatively recent times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command line using `grep -v`:

```
your_command | grep -vxFf <(printf '%s\n' */ | sed 's/.$//') -
```

This will filter out all the sub-directories in current path from your list.

If in case you want to list only existing directories then remove `-v` as:

```
your_command | grep -xFf <(printf '%s\n' */ | sed 's/.$//') -
```

Note that glob `*/` prints all sub-directories in current path with a trailing `/` and `sed` is used to remove this last `/`.